# Why is my Caesar cypher in python off by 1 character?

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I'm new to python coding and tried a challenge that I'm having a hard time with and could use some help. I've gotten pretty much all of the code correct except for one small piece that I can't seem to figure out. My challenge was to take a line of text that the user input and encrypt it using a Caesar cypher. What my code does is take something like "Hello world" and change it into "Lipps$asvph" but what it should say is "Lipps${svph%". At this point I can't figure out why the "{" turned into an "a" but I wanted to ask and see if anyone else can see what the problem might be.

```
distance = int(input("Enter the distance value: "))
code = ""
for ch in message:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordvalue + distance
    if cipherValue > ord('z'):
        cipherValue = ord('a') + distance - \
                      (ord('z') - ordvalue + 1)
    code += chr(cipherValue)
print(code)
```

Comment: because you add 1?

Comment: What is the value of 'd' you're giving in this case?

Comment: as a secondary note, I suggest to use consistent variables names (see "ordvalue" vs "cipherValue"). Also, PEP8 states that Python should use "snake_case" and not "camelCase"

Answer (score 1):

The logic here is:

- shift characters by `distance`
- if the result is above `z`, wrap it around (so, z shifted by 1 turns into a)

The problem: special characters like `{` are out of the `a..z` range, but they're shifted, too. Since the check is only for values above z, those under 'a' are not affected (e.g. '%').

Fix: check if the value is out of readable symbols range (32..255), not `a..z`:

```
max_value = 255  # used to be ord('z')
min_value = 32   # used to be ord('a')
for ch in message:
    ordvalue = ord(ch)
    cipherValue = ordvalue + distance
    if cipherValue > max_value:
        cipherValue = min_value + distance - \
                      (max_value - ordvalue + 1)
    code += chr(cipherValue)
```